# Convert 'DD-MM-YY' to 'Month Year' oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a date a field that displays date in the format `'19-JAN-20'` I would like to display it as `'January 2019'` using oracle database.

```
select '19-JAN-19' FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `TO_CHAR` to display in the required format:

```
select to_char(DATE '2019-01-20', 'Month YYYY') dt from dual;

DT           
-------------
January  2019
```

> select '19-JAN-19' FROM DUAL

There are couple of issues with that statement:

1. `'19-JAN-19'` is a string, not a date. Always use `TO_DATE` to explicitly convert it to date, or stick to **ANSI date literal** like I used in my demo.
2. Do not use **two-digit** `YY` representation for year, that's the reason **Y2K** bug was introduced. Always use `YYYY`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a nested `TO_CHAR`, if "date" value you mentioned - `19-JAN-20` is stored as a string:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '19-JAN-20' from dual)
  3  select
  4    to_char(
  5      to_date(col, 'dd-mon-yy', 'nls_date_language = english'),
  6      'fmMonth yyyy', 'nls_date_language = english'
  7      ) result
  8  from test;

RESULT
--------------
January 2020

SQL>
```

If your database *speaks* English, you can omit the `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` part (mine speaks Croatian so I included it).

---

However, if it is a *date* you'd just want to display differently, then:

(Just to avoid `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` in `TO_DATE`):

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_language = 'english';

Session altered.
```

Default format in my database:

```
SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
--------
08.06.20
```

Alter session to desired format:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'fmMonth yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
--------------
June 2020
```

Or, apply `TO_DATE` function with desired format mask:

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'fmMonth yyyy') result from dual;

RESULT
--------------
June 2020

SQL>
```